# Highlighting a specific node in tikZ matrix when the node has multiple lines of text (beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, highlighting, tikz-matrix

I have a slide with a matrix of nodes that appear one at a time on the slide. Each node has multiple lines of text and math (the sample code shown below was stripped off some of the math to abstract out the details). I wish to highlight one of these nodes after it has appeared, by customising its appearance in some way (for instance, either change the frame colour, or the background colour, etc.) Specifically, in the example below, I'd like to change these features, after the sixth slide, for the very bottom-right node (the one with "stuff 4" in it).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}  
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}
\tcbset{colframe=black, colback=white}              

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill = white,
            inner ysep = 5pt,
            inner xsep = 1pt,
            align = center},
            myplainbox/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center},
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1.6em,
    nodes={anchor=west,
    visible on=<\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2*\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2\relax->,},
    row 1/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
                 text width=12.8em, 
                 text depth = 3.5 em, 
                 text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    column 1/.style={nodes={myplainbox,
            text width=12.8em, 
%            text depth = 3.5 em, 
%            text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    column 2/.style={nodes={myplainbox,
            text width=12.8em, 
%            text depth = 3.5 em, 
%            text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    ](M){
     {some words here\\ $\scriptstyle f(x) - g(x)$ \\ $\scriptstyle \leq  p(x) + q(x) + r(x)$.} &    {some words here\\ $\scriptstyle f(x) - g(x)$ \\ $\scriptstyle \leq  p(x) + q(x) + r(x)$.}\\
     {stuff \\ more stuff} & {stuff 2 \\ more stuff 2}\\
     {stuff \\ more stuff} & {stuff 4 \\ more stuff 4}\\
};          

    \draw[->, thick, visible on = <2->] (M-1-1)--(M-1-2) node[midway, above] {\checkmark}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy: add some local keys to the corresponding matrix element. This works, as described on p. 710 of pgfmanual v3.1.5, by adding `|[<style>]|` with some appropriate style to the matrix element. I just added

```
|[alt=<7>{draw=red,thick,fill=red!20}{}]|
```

to get

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}  
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}
\tcbset{colframe=black, colback=white}              

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill = white,
            inner ysep = 5pt,
            inner xsep = 1pt,
            align = center},
            myplainbox/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center},
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1.6em,
    nodes={anchor=west,
    visible on=<\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2*\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2\relax->,},
    row 1/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
                 text width=12.8em, 
                 text depth = 3.5 em, 
                 text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    column 1/.style={nodes={myplainbox,
            text width=12.8em, 
%            text depth = 3.5 em, 
%            text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    column 2/.style={nodes={myplainbox,
            text width=12.8em, 
%            text depth = 3.5 em, 
%            text height = 1 em, 
    }}, 
    ](M){
     {some words here\\ $\scriptstyle f(x) - g(x)$ \\ $\scriptstyle \leq  p(x) + q(x) + r(x)$.} &    {some words here\\ $\scriptstyle f(x) - g(x)$ \\ $\scriptstyle \leq  p(x) + q(x) + r(x)$.}\\
     {stuff \\ more stuff} & {stuff 2 \\ more stuff 2}\\
     {stuff \\ more stuff} & |[alt=<7>{draw=red,thick,fill=red!20}{}]|{stuff 4 \\ more stuff 4}\\
};          

    \draw[->, thick, visible on = <2->] (M-1-1)--(M-1-2) node[midway, above] {\checkmark}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I want to understand, why is the syntax |[alt=<7>{draw=red,thick,fill=red!20}]|{stuff 4 \\ more stuff 4}. The way I've seen alt used is alt<slide number>{style 1}{alternate style 2}. Here, you wrote two vertical bars that I don't understand, square brackets, and, the hardest for me to parse, the "alternation" seems to be between the style and the content, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @lazulikid In a matrix, you can set the style of an entry with `|[<style>]|`. This has nothing to do with the overlays, but is just "matrix notation", see e.g. p. 710 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.  So `|[alt=<7>{draw=red,thick,fill=red!20}{}]|` just means that we give the matrix element the style. (One can leave out the `{}` here but I agree that it is bad style so will add it to the code above.)

Comment: Thank you again! I looked at the manual and understood that |[<style>]| used right before content (the way you did) adds the specified style to that content. Two more questions: 1) In the alt command, is it that the first option is satisfied when we are on the specified slide, and the second option otherwise ; and is that why you wrote the specified style first and blank in the second option? 2) Also, how do I highlight the commands like you do in your comments? Thanks so much for teaching me so much!

Comment: @lazulikid The definition of the `alt` key can be found on p. 3 of the `overlay-beamer-styles` library: `alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{\alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}`, so yes to your first question. As for the second one, you have to enclose the expression in backticks (on an English keyboard this is often the key left of `1`). This is also described in [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/194703).